# Install Extension using composer not working

Tags: magento2.4

I need to install the following extension on Magneto store:

https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login

I'm using this commend:

```
composer.phar require bitexpert/magento2-force-customer-login
```

but after enter "Authentication required (repo.magento.com)", it is start "Generating autoload files" then the following error appears

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
> content.
>
> [ErrorException]   chmod(): Operation not permitted

as alternative solution, I need to install by coping the files to app/code/ , but I don't know what is exact files and what is the correct steps and commend I need to run after coping the files.

https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login/releases

Magento Version: 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Create below directory and upload extension from github

> app/code/BitExpert/ForceCustomerLogin

Add all files and folder from below path

https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login

and execute below commands

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

```
remove ./composer/cache folder
run composer global update
```